# Unable to load Google products in Google Chrome

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

I've recently upgrade my computer to Ubuntu 14.04. This problem started manifesting after the upgrade.

Any time I try to access a Google product's page (YouTube, Google Calendar, Search, etc.), the page loads a few items (usually the text and CSS), and then spends the rest of the time trying to load the other bits to no avail. I have to stop the page, click Refresh, wait a few minutes for it fail, then click Refresh again. After the second refresh, the page loads as expected. This **only** happens in Google Chrome; Firefox is not affected.

This problem can be mitigated for a while by deleting the `google-chrome` folder in `.config` and re-setup Chrome. This works for a few days before it starts happening again.

What can I do to solve this? I saw that someone on here fixed it by re-installing Ubuntu, but that seems a bit extreme.

Comment: As an update: this turned out to be an issue caused by my router. After switching to a more solid one, the problem vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this:

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
```

Finally, do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```